# Cannot Overlay PNG onto Map with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I am trying to create an `OpenLayers.Layer.Image` and incorporate it into my map. I have this block of code:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map ({
            div: "dvMap",
            theme: null,
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection ("EPSG:4326"),
            maxResolution: 360 / 512,
            center: new OpenLayers.LonLat (-80.92, 40.51),
            zoom: 6,
            layers: [
                 new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS ("TarigmaOSM",
                                           "http://" + maphost + "/cgi-bin/tilecache/tilecache.cgi/",
                                           {
                                                serviceVersion: "1.0.0",
                                                layername: "osm",
                                                type: "png",
                                                attribution: "Data CC-by-SA OpenStreetMap"
                                           }),
                new OpenLayers.Layer.Image ("WeatherImage",
                                            "http://localhost:8080/data/get/weather/radar?stationID=2&productID=2&anticache=" + (new Date ()).getTime (),
                                            new OpenLayers.Bounds (-78.977468899814, 38.770277779319, -84.7329398692738, 41.9763540510698),
                                            new OpenLayers.Size (600, 550),
                                            {

                                            })
            ]
        });
```

When I run this, I get my `TarigmaOSM` layer (base map) just fine, but I don't even see the request for the image layer file in Firebug, nor do I get any problems. Does anyone have any idea what's going on here and/or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try supplying some options for the layer instead of nulling the default options out.

```js
var options = {
    //numZoomLevels: 15,
    isBaseLayer: false,
    maxResolution: "auto",
    resolutions: map.layers[0].resolutions,
    projection: map.getProjectionObject(),
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    displayInLayerSwitcher: true
};
...
new OpenLayers.Layer.Image("WeatherImage",
    "http://localhost:8080/data/get/weather/radar?stationID=2&productID=2&anticache=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
    new OpenLayers.Bounds(-78.977468899814, 38.770277779319, -84.7329398692738, 41.9763540510698),
    new OpenLayers.Size(600, 550),
    options)
...
```

Comment: While that sounded promising, it has had no effect.

Comment: I added edited the options, please try again with `resolutions: map.layers[0].resolutions,`. These work for me. Everything else seems fine. You're sure `http://localhost:8080/data/get/weather/radar?stationID=2&productID=2&anticache=blah` returns an image? Also, FYI unlike WFS requests, you will not see any requests in Firebug for this Image overlay.

Comment: If you're still not seeing it, make sure it's not a very small spec west of Africa. If it is it's just a projection problem.

Comment: Are you seeing it in the layer switcher?

Comment: The URL does return an image (PNG). I added a print in my server code, so I can see when an image is requested. It's not being requested by OpenLayers, but it is visible in the layer switcher.

Comment: I would test with any image you have laying around to compartmentalize and eliminate possibilities.

Comment: I switched to using a static image. When I dig down in Firebug into the HTML after the map is rendered, I find the DIV that should be holding the image; however, it is empty. I feel like I am missing something that causes the image to actually be loaded.

Comment: I suppose you could also try removing it from the array and  adding it like `map.addlayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.Image("...`

Comment: That's what I am doing right now.

Comment: Do you have a public page to access the image or a test link to the static image?  I work with Image layers in my present page and thought about seeing if I could help with your image.

Comment: One thing I have found with Image layers is that Size can determine if they display or not.  This appears to be related to whether you state the layer's maxResolution.  CaptDragon had some good suggestions to troubleshoot.  I'm thinking of perhaps spelling things out even more though it may not seem necessary.  So, spell out maxResolution and projection.  I don't spell out my image layer resolutions nor state displayInLayerSwitcher.  However, I do set visibility: true in the options.  And I don't think strategies is needed.  Think that's primarily for vector layers. Mine haven't needed it.